# how to declare 3d letter array in c language

Tags: arrays, c, character, letter

i wanna declare this array in c:

```
{
  {{'7','P','Q','R','S'},{'8','T','U','V'},{'9','W','X','Y','Z'},{'÷'}},
  {{'4','G','H','I'},{'5','J','K','L'},{'6','M','N','O'},{'×'}},
  {{'1','.','?',',','!'},{'2','A','B','C'},{'3','D','E','F'},{'-'}},
  {{'*'},{'0',' '},{'='},{'+'}}
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Please don't spam language tags. C and C++ are different languages, and both tags are rarely correct for a question.

Comment: https://ideone.com/dx3hLq

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
const wchar_t* array[4][4] = {
  {L"7PQRS", L"8TUV", L"9WXYZ", L"÷"},
  {L"4GHI", L"5JKL", L"6MNO", L"×"},
  {L"1.?,!", L"2ABC", L"3DEF", L"-"},
  {L"*", L"0" ", L"=", L"+"}
};
```

I'm using wide characters because of the funky characters you have but YMMV.

Comment: `L"1.?,!"` doesn't fit into `wchar_t[4]`